# GWTP HttpRequest in Action Handler to get session

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I need to access HttpRequest object in Action handlers in server side of GWTP.

how can I access this information.

For every interaction with server, I need request object.

Please help me.

Using RPC with servlets its absolutely fine we can, but I need it with ActionHandler in GWTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyHandler extends
  AbstractActionHandler<MyAction, MyResult> {


  @Inject
  Provider<HttpServletRequest> requestProvider;

  @Override
  public MyResult execute(MyAction action,  ExecutionContext context) throws ActionException 
  {
      HttpSession session = requestProvider.get().getSession();
  }
}
```

If you use Spring, you need also

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

in web.xml